# @Autowired, Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [...... java.lang.NullPointerException]

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, nullpointerexception, autowired

I am getting the error from my code running LoginController even after adding @Autowired to "private IUserService userService;". Could someone please help? Thanks a lot!

"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null"

Error Msg
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMz97.png)

Code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
@Slf4j 
public class LoginController {


    @Autowired
//    no autowired, nullpointerexception
//    autowired, cannot receive response
    private IUserService userService;


    @RequestMapping("/toLogin") //to log in page 跳转登录页
    public String toLogin(){
        return "login";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/doLogin")
    @ResponseBody
    public RespBean doLogin(LoginVo loginVo) {
        // 接受传参 receive parameter from users with LoginVo
        return userService.doLogin(loginVo);
    }
}
```

```
public interface IUserService extends IService<User> {


    RespBean doLogin(LoginVo loginVo);


}
```

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl<UserMapper, User> implements IUserService {


    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public RespBean doLogin(LoginVo loginVo) {
        String mobile = loginVo.getMobile();
        String password = loginVo.getPassword();

        // check whether input is empty
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(mobile) || StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            return RespBean.error(RespBeanEnum.LOGIN_ERROR);
        }
        // check whether mobile is valid
        if (!ValidatorUtil.isMobile(mobile)) {
            return RespBean.error(RespBeanEnum.MOBILE_ERROR);
        }
        // find user with mobile
        User user = userMapper.selectById(mobile);
        if (user == null) {
            return RespBean.error(RespBeanEnum.LOGIN_ERROR);
        }

        // verify whether user password is correct
        if (!MD5Util.frontPassToDBPass(password, user.getSalt()).equals(user.getPassword())) {
            return RespBean.error(RespBeanEnum.LOGIN_ERROR);

        }
        return RespBean.success();
    }
}
```

Without @Autowired, the login page responses to user input with NullPointerException above anyway.
With @Autowired added, if mobile input is invalid, there is no response. If mobile and password input is valid, the login page responses with NullPointerException above.

I tried adding qualifier with @Component according to website below but it doesn't work.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is best to implement a bean through a constructor, so you can remove Autowired in the LoginController class and create a constructor with the necessary parameter, you can use Lombok
2. since the code is not numbered, it is not clear in which line the npe falls out, but I can assume that in the mapper, you need to check that the service / component annotation is in the mapper class and also create a constructor with a mapper in the service class

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried adding "@AllArgsConstructor" in class UserServiceImpl and adding "@Service" "@Component "to mapper class but it didn't work. The nullpointerexception is pointing to this line "User user = userMapper.selectById(mobile);" under public RespBean doLogin(LoginVo loginVo) of class UserServiceImpl and this line "return userService.doLogin(loginVo);" under class LoginController. Anything else that is wrong with my code? @Jenia Thank you!

Comment: very strange, you need to put on UserServiceImpl service RequiredArgsConstructor and above the mapper service, it must work, if the error occurs again, most likely it is no longer related to the fact that the mapper = null, you can put a dot and check it

Comment: I figured it out!  It worked after adding "@Autowired" above "private UserMapper userMapper;" in public class UserServiceImpl. It was the problem with userMapper injection. Thanks a lot for the help!